# String in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm a french newbie in Python and I would like to code a program which warns us when the time (string "Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds") is wrong (for example, 83 seconds).
I did this program:

```
t=input("Put day,hours,minutes,seconds: ")
t="j,h,m,s"
if int(t[6])<=0 or int(t[6])>=59:
    print("Seconds wrong")
if int(t[4])<=0 or int(t[4])>=59:
    print("Minutes wrong")
if int(t[2])<=0 or int(t[2])>=24:
    print("Hours wrong")
if int(t[0])<=0 or int(t[0])>=31:
    print("days wrong")
else: 
    print("OK")
```

But I've this error:

```
  if t[6]<=0 or t[6]>=59:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()
```

So I put "int" everywhere (like `"int(t[X])<=0"`)
but then I've this error:

```
  if int(t[6])<=0 or int(t[6])>=59:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'
```

Comment: You first ask for `t` from user input, then rebind `t` to a new string, with no integers in it. What do you expect to happen instead? What user input would be given?

Comment: remove the second line, it's rewriting `t` as `"j,h,m,s"`

Comment: Last I checked, `0` and `59` are valid seconds and minutes. You likely want something more like `t[6] < 0 or t[6] >= 60`. Same with the other time units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no digits in this string:

```
t="j,h,m,s"
```

so any attempt to do `int(t[anything])` is going to fail. You can't convert a string to an integer unless the string contains a string representation of an actual integer, such as `t = "1234"`.

Moreover, even if you had something like `t = "31,11,22,45"`, then `int(t[6])` would not give you the number of seconds, because the representation of seconds would be at indices 9 and 10. You'd need `t = int(t[9:11])` in that case.

Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

t = "31,11,22,45"
(day, hour, min, sec) = [int(elem) for elem in t.split(',')]

if not 0 <= sec <= 59:
    print("Seconds wrong")
elif not 0 <= min <= 59:
    print("Minutes wrong")
elif not 0 <= hour <= 23:
    print("Hours wrong")
elif not 1 <= day <= 31:
    print("days wrong")
else:
    print("OK")
```

Note you either need to change all but your first `if` to `elif`, otherwise it'll print `"OK"` if `day` is correct but everything else is wrong, or you'll need to keep some kind of separate variable to store if anything is wrong, and check that at the end, such as in the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

t = "31,11,22,45"
(day, hour, min, sec) = [int(elem) for elem in t.split(',')]
time_ok = True

if not 0 <= sec <= 59:
    print("Seconds wrong")
    time_ok = False

if not 0 <= min <= 59:
    print("Minutes wrong")
    time_ok = False

if not 0 <= hour <= 23:
    print("Hours wrong")
    time_ok = False

if not 1 <= day <= 31:
    print("Days wrong")
    time_ok = False

if time_ok:
    print("Time is OK")
```

Comment: @kren470: Yes, he could.

Comment: Yes I forget the elif, thanks. But how to ask days, hours... in the "DD,HH,MM,SS" format ?

Comment: @Valentln: I don't really understand the question, you could just ask for it: `t = input('Enter the time in DD,HH,MM,SS format:')`

Comment: That's that ! I would like to ask day, hours.. in 4 steps: "Say Days" and the user taps the days. Then "Say hours".... Thanks you very much for your help !

Comment: You could do `days = int(input("Say days: "))` and again for hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thanks. A last question: why "elif" ? On reflexion, if I put "elif" instead of "if", and if I put seconds and minutes wrong, elif say only "Seconds wrong". And with "If", that's say "Minutes and seconds wrong".

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, because otherwise your final `else` statement will only run if `days` is correct, regardless of what anything else if wrong. I'll post an alternative.

Comment: @Valentln: I posted an alternative where you'll get a message for each of the elements that is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. It's strange because when it's "if" only, it's work fine !

Comment: When it's `if` only, it'll only "work fine" if `days` is correct.

Comment: You're right. If sec & min are wrong, it say "sec wrong, min wrong, correct".

Comment: Just a last small question: When you say while smthing: ..... Does that mean smthing==0 ? Thanks

Comment: @Valentln: No, it means while something is true. Truthiness is somewhat of a slippery concept in Python, but for numbers it would mean while the number is *not* zero, for booleans it would mean while the value is `True`, for lists it would mean while the list is not empty, and so on. Any number will evaluate to false if it is zero, and true if it is anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Nice effort, but be careful with the second line:

```
t = "j,h,m,s"
```

This overwrites the user input, and assigning `"j,h,m,s"` to `t` instead. Remove it!

Also, you can't compare it using `or`. Just check if `int(t[6]) > 59` is sufficient.

```
if int(t[6]) > 59:
    print("seconds wrong")
```

A better way to get the comma-separated numbers is to use `string.split()` method.

```
t = t.split(',') #split the string in the commas
```

Now, you don't have to worry about the comma counts. The day would be `t[0]`, the hours would be `t[1]`, and so on.

Ah, also one more thing. You don't have to use if statements repeatedly there. Use it on the first time, and change the next ones with `elif` statements.

Full fixed code:

```
t = input("Put day,hours,minutes,seconds: ")
if int(t[6])>59:
    print("Seconds wrong")
elif int(t[4]) < 0 or int(t[4]) > 59: 
    print("Minutes wrong")
elif int(t[2]) < 0 or int(t[2]) > 24:
    print("Hours wrong")
elif int(t[0]) < 0 or int(t[0]) > 31:
    print("days wrong")
else: 
    print("OK")
```

To be honest, as Paul mentioned, this still won't work if any input is more than one digit.

You'll have to use `string.split()` to achieve this.

```
t = input("Put day,hours,minutes,seconds: ").split(",")

if int(t[3])>59:
    print("Seconds wrong")
elif int(t[2]) < 0 or int(t[2]) > 59: 
    print("Minutes wrong")
elif int(t[1]) < 0 or int(t[1]) > 24:
    print("Hours wrong")
elif int(t[0]) < 0 or int(t[0]) > 31:
    print("days wrong")
else: 
    print("OK")
```

Comment: I'm not yet used to the string format, but I understand what you mean. And I know how to split with comas, thanks for your help !

Comment: Your "fixed code" won't work if the user enters more than one digit for any seconds, minutes, hours, or days.

Comment: Right. I fixed the syntax, but the logic is wrong. Well, i've suggested the working way now.